# German word for "probability score" or "likelihood"?

Tags: mathematics, english

Ich suche Leute, die sowohl eine gewisse mathematische Grundbildung als auch gute Deutsch- und Englischkenntnisse haben.
Speziell geht es um folgende Frage:

Wie bezeichnet man im Deutschen einen konkreten Wert einer Wahrscheinlichkeitsdichtefunktion?

Angenommen, ich habe folgenden Ausdruck:

A = P(X = a), X ∈ {a, b, c}

In diesem Fall würde man ja sagen: „A ist eine Wahrscheinlichkeit“, weil die Zufallsvariable X einen der drei möglichen Werte a, b, c annimmt, und somit P(X) die typischen Bedingungen einer Wahrscheinlichkeit erfüllt (so gilt z.B. immer 0 ≤ P(X) ≤ 1).

Aber zurück zur eigentlichen Frage: Wie nenne ich in folgendem Beispiel das B?

B = p(x = x0), x0 ∈ ℝ

Hier ist p(x) eine Wahrscheinlichkeitsdichtefunktion. Dies bedeutet, das B ja keine Wahrscheinlichkeit ist. Unter anderem kann p(x) ja auch Werte > 1 annehmen, solange das Integral von p(x) über alle x genau = 1 ist.

**Also: Wie würde man B im Deutschen bezeichnen?**
Ich habe in alten (englischsprachigen) Vorlesungsunterlagen von mir den Begriff „probability score“ (statt „probability“) dafür gefunden, und an einigen stellen auch „likelihood“ (wobei das wohl nur in bestimmten Zusammenhängen richtig ist).
Ein schöner, kurzer, knackige Begriff dafür wäre mir sehr lieb.

Comment: I think if you would also provide an english version of your question you could get better answers. I dont think that many here can master german, mathematics (extended level) and english (related to mathematic vocabulary)

Comment: In was für einem Satz würdest du den gesuchten Begriff verwenden wollen? Vielleicht fällt es im Kontext leichter, eine Alternative vorzuschlagen.

Comment: In welchen Zusammenhängen ist „likelihood“ nicht der richtige Begriff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B ist tatsächlich *keine* Wahrscheinlichkeit. ℙ(X=b) oder ℙ(X=x_0) sind jeweils 0, denn das Integrationsintervall hat die Länge 0.

Mein Stochastikprof an der Uni hat es immer vermieden, bei „Wahrscheinlichkeiten mit Dichten“ von konkreten Wahrscheinlichkeiten zu sprechen. Der korrekte Begriff wäre `(Wahrscheinlichkeits)dichte and der Stelle b` oder `Wert der (Wahrscheinlichkeits)dichte bei b`.

Da gerade Stochastiker aber sowieso häufig englisch reden, wurden viele englische Begriffe wie `Likelihood` übernommen. Dadurch erspart man sich, über einen passenden Begriff nachzudenken.

Comment: (Ersteres gilt jedoch nur für Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaße, welche bzgl. des Lebesgue-Maßes absolut stetig sind.)

Comment: Desderwegen ja auch „ℙ“.

Comment: Auf Englisch heißt diese Schreibweise "Blackboard Bold", wie sagt man in Deutschland?

Comment: „Doppelt gestrichen“. Unicode nennt die Zeichen auch „double struck“ und nicht „blackboard bold“.

Comment: @Toscho Ist es üblich, Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaße mit Dichte bzgl. des Lebesgue-Maßes mit einem doppelgestrichenen „P“ zu bezeichnen? Ich kenn’ mich da nicht so aus. Andere Frage: Wie gibst du das Zeichen ein?

Comment: @K.Stm. Also an meiner Uni haben es mehrere Profs so gemacht, Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaße mit doppeltgestrichenem P zu schreiben. Das wird sicherlich auch anders gemacht, insbesondere von Leuten, die doppelt gestrichene Buchstaben ablehnen. Das Zeichen ist im Unicode bei u+2119. Wie du es eingibst, hängt von deinem Betriebssystem und der eingesetzten Software ab. Ich z.B. brauche nur Strg+Shift+u oder Strg+u eingeben, um beliebige Unicodezeichen auszuspucken.

Comment: @Toscho Ne, ich meine, ob man „ℙ“ (danke für den Code) nur für Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaße (auf einem Teil des ℝⁿ), welche bzgl. des Lebesgue-Maßes stetig sind verwendet, und für andere Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaße dann auf „P“ ausweicht oder so? Weil du hast ja geschrieben „Deswegen ja auch ℙ“?

Comment: @K.Stm. eher ersteres.

Answer (score 4):

Es ist sinnvoll, im Deutschen den Anglizismus „*Likelihood*“ zu verwenden:

Der maximum likelihood estimator wird ja im Deutschen auch als „[Maximum-Likelihood-Schätzer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-Likelihood-Methode)“ bezeichnet und die likelihood function als „[Likelihood-Funktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-Funktion)“. Die Verwendung dieses Anglizismus ist innerhalb der Statistik also durchaus konsistent und gibt außerdem jenen anderen Begriffen sogar mehr Struktur.

Nachtrag: Ach, das schlägt auch mein Lieblings-Onlinewörterbuch in sochen Fragen, [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=likelihood), vor.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Mathematikkenntnisse sind zwar mittlerweile recht verblasst, aber rein semantisch gesehen müsste das Ergebnis einer [Dichtefunktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichtefunktion) die **Dichte** (oder der **Dichtewert**) sein.

Man kann, um Verwechslungen zu vermeiden außerhalb des Kontexts natürlich auch von einer **Wahrscheinlichkeitsdichte** reden.

Comment: Das Problem ist allerdings, daß man eine _Dichtefunktion_ selbst auch _Dichte_ nennt. – Ich würde vermutlich „Dichte an der Stelle x0“ oder so etwas sagen.